# Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column. Getting error only in Shared Hosting cPanel

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, cpanel

I'm working on a project in Codeigniter 3. Everything was going fine but when i uploaded my project to shared hosting cPanel. I got this error.

> Error Number: 42000/1055
>
> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
> nonaggregated column 'siyabdev_smart_school.classes.id' which is not
> functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

The issues appears only in the cPanel. I tried editing variables inside ***phpmyadmin*** of shared hosting. (tried editing sql_mode and removing the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`), but i got a permission error.

> #1227 - Access denied, You need (at least one of) the SUPER privilge(s) for this operation.

I'm stuck and searched for the similar questions ***but that did not help***. Any idea how to get rid of these errors.

My Code.

```
public function get_classes () {
            $q = $this->db->select('
                    `classes`.`id`,
                    `classes`.`class`, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(`sections`.`section`) AS sections, 
                    `classes`.`created_at`
                ')
                    ->join('classes', '`classes`.`id` = `class_sections`.`class_id`', 'inner')
                    ->join('sections', '`sections`.`id` = `class_sections`.`section_id`', 'inner')
                    ->group_by("`classes`.`class`")
                    ->get('class_sections');

            return $q->result();
        }
```

Comment: You only group by `class`, but you have `created_at` and `id` in the select as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `ANY_VALUE`

In your query you have group by class but in select there is id , created_at
Try like this

```
$q = $this->db->select('
                ANY_VALUE(`classes`.`id`) AS id,
                `classes`.`class`, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(`sections`.`section`) AS sections, 
                ANY_VALUE(`classes`.`created_at`) AS created_at
            ')
```